# Pascal Lazaruz doesn't do its division properly for some instances

Tags: pascal, division, lazarus

```
program Project1;

var p : real;

const s=439 ;

begin
     p:=s/100;
     Write(p);
     ReadLn;
end.
```

Output of the above code is expected to be 4.39, but this gives  4.3899999999999997E+000.
Where do these additional 89999999 came from? How to omit this and get the correct answer?
Thanks in advance!

P.S. If we assign s = 433 it gives the expected output as  4.3300000000000001E+000. My issue is, how this division can be number related?

Edit: I want to know a remedy to overcome this inaccuracy. It may be a code line or two, what ever possible to get rid of this issue.

Comment: It's a question of how e.g. real-type numbers are represented as a limited number of bits.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you so much for the link provided. It solves my issue half-way, but I need to know whether there's any remedy to fix this.

Comment: There's no way to eliminate rounding errors like this, but you can round the result to the desired precision when outputting it with e.g. `Write(p:7:2);`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Could you kindly explain your example? I'm a beginner to Pascal.

Comment: Here, `p:7:2` instruct `Write` to display the value of variable `p` in a 7-character field, with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me give a try.

Comment: You can do this arithmetic the way you want. You just been to use a decimal type rather than a binary type.